# How many controllers a CronusMAX can handle in a time?

Tags: controllers

I wanted to buy a [CronusMAX](http://cronusmax.com/) but this is not clear for me.
The main goal is to share multiple controllers between an XBox360 and an XBox One.

Can i use an USB hub and plug multiple wired (XB1) controllers on an XBox 360?
Can i use multiple keyboards and mouses with a hub?
Can i use multiple wireless XBox360 controller on an XBox One using an Xbox 360 Wireless Gaming Receiver? (It support multiple controllers on OSX and Win)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From what it looks like you can't use multiple wireless controllers through CronusMAX at once.](http://cronusmax.com/instructions/using-xbox-360-wireless-controllers/) Although it does look like you can use one CronusMAX in addition to 3 normal controllers.

[This provides information regarding non-hub controller support](http://cronusmax.com/cross-over-gaming/)
, but the original link does state that you can only use one controller through the adapter at once. So I'm going to say you can only use one.